# Matplotlib: xticks every 15 minutes, starting on the hour

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, ticker

I am trying to plot values of temperature against time with the time formatted as HH:MM. I am able to set the xticks to recur every 15 minutes but the first tick is at the first time (e.g. 04:40).

Is there a way to shift the ticks to occur on the hour and on the concurrent quarter-hours (04:45, 05:00, 05:15, etc.)? My current code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import datetime as dt

## Dummy times and temperatures
time = [dt.datetime(2017,2,15,4,40),dt.datetime(2017,2,15,4,46),dt.datetime(2017,2,15,4,52),dt.datetime(2017,2,15,4,58),dt.datetime(2017,2,15,5,4),dt.datetime(2017,2,15,5,10)]
temp = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

## Plot the data
figtemp, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(time, temp)

## Set time format and the interval of ticks (every 15 minutes)
xformatter = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
xlocator = md.MinuteLocator(interval = 15)

## Set xtick labels to appear every 15 minutes
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xlocator)

## Format xtick labels as HH:MM
plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformatter)
```

Comment: answer by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest solves the problem IMHO, why aren't you marking it as accepted?

Answer (score 29):

You could tell the `MinuteLocator` to only use the minutes `0,15,30,45` using the `byminute` argument.

```
xlocator = md.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,15,30,45], interval = 1)
```

Comment: how does is supposed to help me? Where shall I use xlocator variable? and what is `md`?

Comment: @Intelligent-Infrastructure You need to read the Question and the answer!

Answer (score -2):

Use [`Axes.set_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels),

```
labels = ['04:45', '05:00', '05:15']
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(labels)
```

which produces,

[image]

---

Shift time to the concurrent quarter-hours,

```
import datetime

list_dt = [ datetime.datetime(2017,2,15,4,40),
            datetime.datetime(2017,2,15,4,46),
            datetime.datetime(2017,2,15,4,52),
            datetime.datetime(2017,2,15,4,58),
            datetime.datetime(2017,2,15,5,4),
            datetime.datetime(2017,2,15,5,10)]

adjust_list_dt = list()

for dt in list_dt:
    print(dt.minute//15)

    if dt.minute % 15 == 0:
        adjust_minutes = dt.minute
    else:
        adjust_minutes = (dt.minute//15 + 1)*15

    if adjust_minutes == 60:
        adjust_list_dt.append(dt.replace(hour=dt.hour+1, minute=0))
    else:
        adjust_list_dt.append(dt.replace(minute=adjust_minutes))

print(adjust_list_dt)
# Output
'''
[datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 15, 4, 45), 
 datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 15, 5, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 15, 5, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 15, 5, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 15, 5, 15), 
 datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 15, 5, 15)]
'''
```

Comment: The problem here is that you would need to know the hours where the data occurs beforehands. Also it's pretty unhandy to have to type the times in by hand.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, pls checked my edited answer. I believe your solution is more elegant.

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem of manually setting the hours and minutes. Nice. But it is indeed a little complicated for a task that can be done in one line.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I agree. Just upvoted ur answer.